# List View Items Deleted When Back Button Pressed Android

Tags: android, json

I am new to android development. I have implemented an activity which is Loading Json data to a listview. I have two activities now. First one is login Activity.Second one is loading list view activity.the json data is loading perfectly. but my problem is, when i pressed back button, the list view data is removing one by one. i have no idea where the problem is.

here is my main activity

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        ListView list;
        TextView ver;
        TextView name;
        TextView api;
        ImageButton login;

        public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist;  

        //URL to get JSON Array
        private static String url = "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/";

        //JSON Node Names
         static final String TAG_OS = "android";
         static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
         static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
         static final String TAG_API = "api";

        JSONArray android = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.loging);

            oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            login = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                 public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new JSONParse().execute();

            }
        }); 
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
            ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
            name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist);
            api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
           pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
           pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
           pDialog.setCancelable(true);
           pDialog.show();

       }


       @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

           // Getting JSON from URL
           JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
           return json;
    }


       @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           pDialog.dismiss();
           try {
                  // Getting JSON Array from URL
                  android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                  for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                  JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                  // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                  String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                  String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                  String api = c.getString(TAG_API);

                  // Adding value HashMap key => value

                  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                  map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                  map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                  map.put(TAG_API, api);

                  oslist.add(map);

                  Intent reult = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewList.class);
                  //reult.putStringArrayListExtra("map", oslist);
                  //startActivity(reult);


                  reult.putExtra("arraylist", oslist);
                  startActivityForResult(reult, 500);



                  }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

       }
  }
    }
```

Here is my Listview Activity

```
 public class ViewList extends Activity {

        private static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_API = "api";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Intent getres = getIntent();
        //HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)getres.getSerializableExtra("map");

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");

        ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

       /* ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ViewList.this, arl,
                R.layout.row,
                new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                        R.id.title,R.id.artist, R.id.time});*/

        NewsRowAdapter adapter = new NewsRowAdapter(ViewList.this, R.layout.row, arl);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewList.this, "You Clicked at "+arl.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

this is my Adapter Class

```
 public class NewsRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /*//ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
    //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;


    private List<Item> items;
    //private Item objBean;
    private int row;*/
    private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    int resource;
        //String response;
        //Context context;
        //Initialize adapter
        public NewsRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
            super();
            this.resource=resource;
            this.data = d;
            this.activity = act;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }



    /*public NewsRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData)) {
        super(act, resource, arrayList);
        this.activity = act;
        this.row = resource;
        this.data = arrayList;
    }*/

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


        View vi = convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);

            TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            TextView time = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.time);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song =data.get(position);

            title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_VER));
            artist.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_NAME));
            time.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_API));
            //imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), img);

            Button accept = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnaccept);
            accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //CustomizedListView getlist = new CustomizedListView();

                    final int x = (int) getItemId(position);

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"you clicked "+ x , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "view clicked: " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return vi;








    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }



    @Override
    public Object getItem(int possision) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return possision;
    }



    @Override
    public long getItemId(int possision) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return possision;
    }
}
```

please some one help me...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will do so, When you press back button your activity get finished , So the view inside the activity will get deleted , Either you must keep the data in a seperate class, outside activity or keep the activity alive.

Comment: hi arju, can you give me some example how to do it... please :)

Comment: on back pressed are you moving to other activity or exiting the app

Comment: it should move to the activity to previous activity. but i didn't code to that because it automatically append to my previous projects.

Comment: Define a class and keep the string within that class you should transfer that object between these actvity. Dont loose the object